# Blur filter works, but check50 disagrees

Tags: c, cs50

I've been working on problem set four of the CS50 computer science course and ran into a problem in the blur filter that I'm not sure how to fix. This filter is meant to, for each pixel, take the average of all the color values in a 3x3 area within the current pixel, and change the middle pixel using the average of those pixels. My filter is blurring the picture, but is a little off of what check50 requires. Here's my code.

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];

    for (int i = 0;i < height;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0;j < width;j++)
        {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0;i < height;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0;j < width;j++)
        {
            int redAvrg = 0;
            int blueAvrg = 0;
            int greenAvrg = 0;
            int count = 0;

            for (int x = i - 1;x < i + 2;x++)
            {
                for (int y = j - 1;y < j + 2;y++)
                {
                    if(x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < height && y < width)
                    {
                        redAvrg += copy[x][y].rgbtRed;
                        blueAvrg += copy[x][y].rgbtBlue;
                        greenAvrg += copy[x][y].rgbtGreen;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(redAvrg / count);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blueAvrg / count);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(greenAvrg / count);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a link for the exact specification for the problem?

Comment: Remember that integer division yields an integer result - `1/2 == 0`, `3/2 == 1`, etc.  You may want to cast your `xxxAvrg` or `count` to `double` before doing the division, and then round the result - `image[i][j].rgbtRed = round( (double) redAvrg / count );`

Comment: Yes, the integer division already truncated the average value, so `round()` did nothing.

Comment: Thank you John Bode and Weather Vane, you were right. Your solution fixed everything!